# Is there more elegant method for filtering dicts in python

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, python-2.6

I am wondering
is it possible to filter a dict more shortly than

```
>>> a={1:'a',2:'b',3:'c',4:'d',5:'e'}
>>> filterlist=[1,3,5]
>>> b=dict((key,value) for key,value in a.iteritems() if key in filterlist)
>>> b
{1: 'a', 3: 'c', 5: 'e'}
```

the filtering(*sorting*) might be based on values or keys

*EDIT1* :as mentioned in the below comments its filtering not sorting

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: Sort a dictionary by value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/python-sort-a-dictionary-by-value) and [python dictionary sort by key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001509/python-dictionary-sort-by-key)

Comment: "sorting"? There is no sorting here...

Comment: Python dictionaries *have no set order*; you cannot sort the keys in a dictionary. You can produce a *sorted list* of keys and/or values, but not a sorted dictionary.

Comment: Since python 2.7, there is a [collections.OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), that remembers the order of keys were first inserted.

Comment: Well, shorter than the one line you already have? `dict(i for i in a.items() if i[0] in filterlist)`

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean filtering, not sorting. Here's a more elegant way(IMO) to filter a dictionary by keys using dictionary comprehension:

```
>>>a = {1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c', 4:'d', 5:'e'}
>>>filterlist = [1, 3, 5]
>>>b= {key: a[key] for key in filterlist}
>>>b
{1: 'a', 3: 'c', 5: 'e'}
```

Comment: Thank you Milan
but i tried this in 2.6.x
and it gives me syntax error

Comment: @Koetsuji Maybe you should use the python-2.6 tag and not the python-2.7 tag in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Use OrderedDict as mentioned in the comments

Sorting based on keys:

```
b = OrderedDict(sorted([(key, value) for (key,value) in a.items()]))
```

Sorting based on value:

```
b = OrderedDict(sorted([(value, key) for (key,value) in a.items()]))
```